# General Function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax.net

in a project I am working on I have TabContainer (AJAX.NET) have many tabPanels all of them are doing the same function **BUT** each on on a **different Table**

***let me give a sample :***

```
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer3" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" BorderStyle="None"
    BorderWidth="0" CssClass="MyTabStyle" Width="625px">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Tab_x
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_x" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnx" runat="server" Text="Button" />                
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Tab_y
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_y" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btny" runat="server" Text="Button" />                
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Code behind (VB.NET)

```
Protected Sub btnx_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnx.Click
    SaveText_x(txt_x.Text)
End Sub

Protected Sub btny_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btny.Click
    SaveText_y(txt_y.Text)
End Sub
```

is there a way to create general Sub or Function so if I clicked **btnx** function Save_x(txt_x.Text) be called

and when I click **btny** function Save_y(txt_y.Text) be called ?

Comment: How you assign event handler to button click event?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign multiple buttons to have the same click handler with the following code :

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnx.Click, btny.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.ID = "btnx" Then
        SaveText_x(txt_x.Text)
    ElseIf btn.ID = "btny" Then
        SaveText_y(txt_y.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Both btnx and btny will both fire this Sub and it will check the button that sent it to see which method to call.

Comment: what I am looking for is to write less code, but the way you suggest will cost me lot of time and make the code so complex

Comment: @Thair You don't have many options to shorten what you already have, You **have** to specify each individual method to call (i.e. the `SaveText_x`) and the field to pass (i.e. the `txt_x`). There is no possible way to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

1)Made user control with public string property. use view state to store value of that property.

2)Add that user control into your tabs set that property with values like "X" or "Y" or any.

3)On button click check that property with if .. else if .. else or by switch statement and call your SaveText functions variants.